# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied chown

Tags: python

ok so i was doing the website blocker thing and i had to link the hosts file to the code by writing the path **C:/and stuff** but this error shows up, i tried using the chown but i dont know how its kind of complicated
heres the code without the chown

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

hosts_path=r"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"
website_list=["www.facebook.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.roblox.com"]
final_list=[redirect + " " + i for i in website_list]
final_string_block="\n".join(final_list)

while True:
   if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,14) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,21):
       print("Within time...")
       with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
           content=file.read()
           for website in website_list:
               if website in content:
                   pass
               else:
                   file.write(redirect+ " "+ website+"\n")
   else:
       with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
           content=file.readlines()
           file.seek(0)
           for line in content:
               if not any(website in line for website in website_list):
                   file.write(line)
           file.truncate()
   time.sleep(2.5)
```

and heres the code with the chown

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os

os.chown("C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts")

hosts_path=r"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"
website_list=["www.facebook.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.roblox.com"]
final_list=[redirect + " " + i for i in website_list]
final_string_block="\n".join(final_list)

while True:
    if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,14) < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,21):
        print("Within time...")
        with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
            content=file.read()
            for website in website_list:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    file.write(redirect+ " "+ website+"\n")
    else:
        with open(hosts_path, "r+") as file:
            content=file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in content:
                if not any(website in line for website in website_list):
                    file.write(line)
            file.truncate()
    time.sleep(2.5)
```

so ik i did the chown wrong please help

Comment: (a) [`os.chown` shouldn't be available on Windows](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os%20chown#os.chown). (b) You haven't provided a `uid` or `gid`. (c) You'd have to run as root for a chown to work.

Comment: well i tried running on cmd as admin and it worked thanks bro